# Are there any memory tests that will identify the slot where an error occured?

Tags: memory, memtest86+

I'm experiencing symptoms that in the past have always led to a RAM issue, but in the past have had to go through the incredibly tedious process of working through a variety of lengthy RAM tests that involve checking each RAM stick individually, and then sometimes pairing them in various sequences.

It's the year 2015. This is the "Future", according to Back to the Future. Surely there must be a memory tester out there that will tell me which slot on my motherboard holds the RAM that is producing errors, if errors are found?